# Killed Enzymes in Yogurt

Tags: yogurt

We are big dairy eaters in our home, so I successfully make about a gallon of Greek yogurt every few weeks. Today I started my process as usual, but with so many things happening at once (just had my 2nd baby, so things are hectic), I failed to remember to let the milk cool before adding in my enzymes: I stirred them in right at 180 degrees. So having killed my enzymes (*sigh*), what can I do with all of this milk/yogurt mix aside from throwing it down the sink? Pardon my stupidity and lack of knowledge on the subject, but would the heating process alter at all the calories/nutrients in the milk/yogurt in any way (aside from the obvious death of the innocent enzymes)? Will my milk curdle or something? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Why not just add more enzymes after the stuff cooled sufficiently?

Enzymes you add to food are generally not toxic. If you [denature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_%28biochemistry%29) them by getting them too hot, they don't usually renature spontaneously when the food cools down. They'll just act like a gram, or whatever amount, of protein added to your yogurt mix.
Adding fresh enzymes once the milk is cool enough won't hurt anything. Those new, happy enzymes will just do their enzymatic thing, and give you the yogurt you want.

Comment: You are correct about denatured enzymes, but in this case, I think the OP misspoke. Homemade yogurt is typically made with live bacterial culture. I'm not aware of a process which uses pure enzymes to make yogurt (although there are such processes for cheese). Anyway, the bacteria won't return back from death either.

Comment: @rumtscho - Bacteria *do* make handy containers to carry enzymes around; self-replicating too. Going to purified enzymes when bugs have worked fine for centuries does seem a bit of a stretch too. Recipe may emphasize the bacterial *enzymes* bit rather than the organisms themselves.